# Pivot in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I have the following procedure to dynamically pivot a table, but i am getting an error.

```
DECLARE @List varchar(5000)
DECLARE @CNT int
DECLARE @metric varchar(500)

SET @LIST = ''
DECLARE crs_TERRMETRICLIST CURSOR FOR SELECT 
METRIC_NAME FROM TEMP.ALLTERRDISTINCTMETRICNAMES



OPEN crs_TERRMETRICLIST 
FETCH NEXT FROM crs_TERRMETRICLIST INTO @metric
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
--SELECT @LIST = @LIST+@metric+','
SELECT @LIST =  @LIST+''''+@metric+''''+','
--SET @LIST = COALESCE(@LIST,'''','')
FETCH NEXT FROM crs_TERRMETRICLIST INTO @metric
END
SET @LIST = LEFT(@LIST,LEN(@LIST)-1)
CLOSE crs_TERRMETRICLIST
DEALLOCATE crs_TERRMETRICLIST

PRINT @LIST
---SET @list = SELECT DISTINCT METRIC_NAME FROM TEMP.ALLTERRMETRICS

SELECT TERRITORY_ID, METRIC_NAME, METRIC_VALUE
FROM TEMP.ALLTERRMETRIC
PIVOT
(MAX(METRIC_VALUE)
FOR METRIC_NAME IN (@LIST)
) as pvt
ORDER BY pvt.TERRITORY_ID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare pivot using a variable like you did. You can declare the last bit as dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'SELECT TERRITORY_ID, METRIC_NAME, METRIC_VALUE
FROM TEMP.ALLTERRMETRIC
PIVOT
(MAX(METRIC_VALUE)
FOR METRIC_NAME IN (' + @LIST ')
) as pvt
ORDER BY pvt.TERRITORY_ID'

exec (@sql)
```